# PHP zerofill number to always have two chars

Tags: php, char, printf, number-formatting

I want to zerofill a number so that the resulting nunber always has two chars.

For example:
1.7 -> 01.7
34.7 -> 34.6 // Remains the same, already two chars

I tried using `printf('%05.1f', 12.2);` but this always adds a char to the number no matter what. I only want that to happen when it has only one char (< 10). Also decimals should not be removed.

Comment: `printf('%04.1f', 12.2);`

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
printf('%04.1f', 12.2)
```

because you want your numbers to have at least four characters (including the .)

You may want to check out this:
http://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet#printf_-_floating_point_numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can use if else for that

```
if($num <10){
  printf('%05.1f', 12.2);
}
```